# My android studio is not opening on windows 10

Tags: android

[image]

How can I fix this problem? I tried everything that I could find in google.

Comment: Hi! And welcome. For best results, inclue as much info as possible about: 1. What you’ve tried so far, 2. What you’re trying to accomplish, 3. What your current setup is, and 4. What the current behaviour is.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

- Uninstall Android Studio
- Delete C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Google folder
- Delete C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android folder
- Delete C:\Users\USER\.android folder
- Delete C:\Users\USER\.gradle folder
- Install JDK 8 and latest version of JDK
- Make sure you are connected to the internet and reinstall Android Studio
- If that still doesn't work, you may have to reinstall your Windows.